# How to check search engine if you dont have confirm button on the page(webdriver io) and confirm the results with matching

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

web: `https://new.flatlay.io/` you can use my credentials to

`loging: kosarsute@gmail.com', pass'qalesson@gmail.com'`  go to search page
and try to search for adidas

I also don't know how to confirm that we got relevant search results , if you can give me examples

**Code trial :**

```
auth.$log.click(); 
auth.login('kosarsute@gmail.com', 'qalesson@gmail.com' ) 
auth.$searchCLick.click(); auth.$search.click(); 
auth.$search.setValue("nike")

const searchResult = $('[class="creator-content"]').getText() expect(searchResult).to.match('nike')
```

Comment: Is there any code that you have tried ?

Comment: auth.$log.click();
        auth.login('kosarsute@gmail.com', 'qalesson@gmail.com' )
        auth.$searchCLick.click();
        auth.$search.click();
        auth.$search.setValue("nike");

Comment: and like it inputs nike in search engine but i can press search button because there is no search button, idk what command should i use to just hit enter from keyboard lol

Comment: browser.keys("\uE007");  i found this command for hitting enter, now have to confirm all matches in a page

Comment: const searchResult = $('[class="creator-content"]').getText()
        expect(searchResult).to.match('nike') can i use this command to confirm search match?

Comment: No you can simply assert whatever you see consistent after logging, that would tell your script that it has validate the sign. also use @ to reply.